# How to optimize 3 variables to a minimum in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization

So I have the following data frame as an exmaple:

`data <- data.frame(   L = runif(100, 15,35), H = runif(100, 1, 3),   B = runif(100, 4, 12),   V = L*B*H    q_A = 2520/(L*B),    v_h = 0.7/(H*B) )`

What I need is to optimize to a minimum `V, q_A and V_h` simultaneously.

I have explored optimization packages as well as the built in optimzation functions. However, I am failing to formulate the problem with the correct syntax to get the right answers error free.

The expected outcome is a data point from the data frame which hast optimal minimum outcome for the 3 variables. In a 3-dimensional plot that would be the points closest to the origin.

Edit:

so here is the real data:

Please ignore the way the data was created, it was made to comply with several conditions. The solution was also posted here on stackoverlow.

```
    B0 <- 1:4999
    L0 <- 1:4999
    H0 <- 1:4999
    
    BL <- matrix(numeric(), ncol = 2, nrow = 0)
    for (L in L0) {
      keep <- B0*L >= 420 & B0*L < 5000
      if (any(keep))
        BL <- rbind(BL, cbind(B0[keep], L))
    }
    
    BLH <- matrix(numeric(), ncol = 3, nrow = 0)
    for (H in H0) {
      keep <- BL[, 1]*H >= 14 & BL[,1]*BL[,2]*H < 5000
      if (any(keep))
        BLH <- rbind(BLH, cbind(BL[keep, , drop=FALSE], H))
    }
    
    rm(BL,B0,H,H0,keep,L,L0) # delete unneeded values
    
    BLH <- as.data.frame(BLH) %>% dplyr::rename(B = 1) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(V = B*L*H, q_A = 2520/(L*B), v_h = 0.7/(H*B))
```

[Here is the 3 Dimensional Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ9HB.png)

Now if I use the norm that a user below suggestet I get the 1st row to be the one

```
which.min(BLH$V^2+BLH$q_A^2+BLH$v_h^2)
```

Looking at the plot, it seems to not be the one.

```
car::scatter3d(BLH$V, BLH$v_h, BLH$q_A, surface = F)
```

From that plot I need points which are visually closest to the origin, without regarding the scales for now. I need the curved area (or point) closest to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the task is to the find the point (row) which has closest distance to the origin, using the last 3 variables. If so all you need is a norm

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(   
  L = runif(100, 15,35), 
  H = runif(100, 1, 3),  
  B = runif(100, 4, 12))
data$V = with(data,L*B*H)
data$q_A = with(data,2520/(L*B))
data$v_h = with(data,0.7/(H*B))
```

and the norm

```
> which.min(data$V^2+data$q_A^2+data$v_h^2)
[1] 43
```

Comment: That seems to be correct. Is there a way to show a range of closest points (rows), so that it may be displayed in 3-D Plot in the next step ?

Comment: You can sort the norm to get the exact ordering, you can then select as many rows as you want `sort(data$V^2+data$q_A^2+data$v_h^2,index.return=T)`.

Comment: Why did you pick this formula? Why the square?

Comment: I am seeing now the answer seems to not be making a lot of sense when looking at the 3 dimensional plot. I will edit the main post and show the full data, so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Julien It's arbitrary, however this particular norm is also called the Euclidean norm and is the most commonly used norm.

Comment: Does this norm make sense in a 3 dimensional plot with different scales on the axis ? I dont think it does, which is confirmed by looking at the 3-D Plot I posted above.

Comment: @FlameAA The trouble with the 3D image you posted is that the axis of each variable is rescaled such that they all have the same width on the graph from min to max of the variable range, which creates the illusion that the points are nicely distributed around the origin in some sort of semi-cylindrical shape. However that is not the case, if you plot the variables on the original scale, that is with each axis starting at 0 up to max, you would see a very different picture, and in that picture the first row is closest to the origin.